# How to make tasks execute one after another?

Tags: java, android, gradle

Basically I have 4 tasks that I need to run sequentially, but I cannot make them do so, I have to run it one by one on the command line as so:

```
gradle :drmdexsecondary:compileReleaseJava --info --debug --stacktrace
gradle :drmdexsecondary:dexClasses --info --debug --stacktrace
gradle :drmdexsecondary:jar --info --debug --stacktrace
```

Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
evaluationDependsOnChildren();

    task dexClasses( type:Exec ) {
    
    //    compileJava.execute()
    
        String cmdExt = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? '.bat' : ''
    
        println("${buildDir}")
        println("${androidSdkDir}\\build-tools\\${buildToolsVersion}\\dx${cmdExt} --dex --output=${buildDir}\\classes\\classes.dex ${buildDir}\\classes\\release")
    
        commandLine "cmd", "/c", "${androidSdkDir}\\build-tools\\${buildToolsVersion}\\dx${cmdExt} --dex --output=${buildDir}\\classes\\classes.dex ${buildDir}\\classes\\release"
    }
    
    task jar(type: Jar) {
        from ("${buildDir}\\classes\\classes.dex")
    }
```

My problem is this:

1. the `dependsOn` keyword doesn't work... it just get ignored without any log message
2. `taskname.execute()` function doesn't work... it just get ignored without any log message
3. `compileReleaseJava` is not recognized inside build.gradle with this particular error: `Could not find property 'compileJava' on task ':drmdexsecondary:dexClasses'.`

Would anyone please help?

I've consulted and copy paste from the documentation but none of them seems work. I've even tried to re-install Gradle... there is so few sample codes there and although I understand the concept, it seems so difficult to translate my intention into working Gradle code, so if there is any good resources to help, it will be very appreciated as well.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should read about [gradle tasks](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html) and [more about tasks](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html).  You want to depend on things rather then invoke things.

Also I think you should read about, and use the [gradle android plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide).

To your original question, when you define a task the code between the braces is run at configuration time.  A task's actions are run when the task is executed and must be added to the task's action list.  This is done by using the task's doFirst, doLast or the << operator.

Here is an example from the gradle documentation.

```
task taskX << {
    println 'taskX'
}
task taskY << {
    println 'taskY'
}
task taskZ << {
    println 'taskZ'
}
taskX.dependsOn taskY
taskY.dependsOn taskZ
taskZ.shouldRunAfter taskX
```

Comment: I do agree that this is preferable when possible, but often some plugins etc. provide some well established commonly used tasks and you'd want to plug in some special beahviour to those. You could define your special task which depends on these, but if these tasks are well known changes are some developers don't even notice your special variant of the task and instead call the well generally well known `test` or `publish` tasks directly as there's no way to make those private.

Answer (score 34):

`task1.finalizedBy task2` will run task2 after task1.

Comment: How do I make it run only if previous tasks succeeded?

Comment: Ok, adding this seems to do the trick `task2.onlyIf { task1.state.failure == null }`

Answer (score 6):

### The Best Answer is Here

```
task myTask1() {
  println("this is task1 running") 
}

task task2() { dependsOn myTask1
  println("this is task2 running") 
}
```

when you execute  **gradle task2** .

this wil  first execute task1  ,and then  execute task2

### you should use dependsOn key words

For example

```sh
task buildMyApk(type: Exec) {
    def myCommond = ['gradle', "assembleRelease"]
    commandLine myCommond
}



task moveApkFileToProjectFolder() { dependsOn buildMyApk
    def releaseApkFilePath = "${buildDir}/outputs/apk/release/"
    def targetApkFolder = "${rootProject.getProjectDir()}/apkFolder"
    mkdir "${targetApkFolder}"
    copy{
        from releaseApkFilePath
        into targetApkFolder
    }
}
```

above answer will not work
task moveApkFileToProjectFolder run ,will first run buildMyApk.

my example task ,first will build apks .and then move apk File to my Project/apkFile folder .and execute success.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a task of type `GradleBuild` and define the tasks inside of that task.

```
  task releaseAfterMath(type: GradleBuild) {
      tasks = [
        'clean', 
        'build',
        'publish',
        'publishToMavenLocal',
        'commitNewVersionTask', 
        'gitChangelogTask', 
        'commitChangelogTask'
      ]
  }
```

And you can trigger `releaseAfterMath` like any other task. Running code here:

https://github.com/tomasbjerre/gradle-scripts/

Answer (score 1):

For sequential or whatever the sequence you want to run your tasks, I do the following thing in my build.gradle file:

```
def modules = ["X", "Y", "Z", "ZZ"]

if (modules.size() > 1) {
    for(j in 1 .. modules.size()-1 ) {
        tasks[modules[j]].mustRunAfter  modules[values[j-1]]        
     }
}
```

Comment: This is not a "pretty" way how to do things but rather a "hack". I would not advise to do this. As previous answer states - Gradle concept is "depend on things"